# Only 10 of 233 categories selectable when adding a new post

Tags: categories, block-editor

In WordPress 5.1.1 in the new block editor. I have 233 categories in the backend, but when adding a new post from backend then it's showing only 10 categories:

[image]

How can I make all categories showing up instead of just 10?

Comment: Does the autocomplete work if you search for a category not in that list?

Comment: I have checked WordPress not provide autocomplete feature for the category selection.

Comment: But if you search - does it only return 10 or does the search show you some of of the other categories?

Comment: If we search anything then category list not update, it's showing by default 10 category.